# Replace nth line in file from different file

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

I have a number of files in different subdirectories, where one subdirectory contains a file with correct information in the 6th line and the others contain only dummy information. The directory structure is like this:

```
Folder-1
    Subfolder-1
        File-A
   SubfFolder-2
        File-B
    Subfolder-3
        File-B
Folder-2
    ...
Folder-3
...
```

`File-A` in `Subfolder-1` contains the correct text in line 6, which is a string that is different for each `Folder`. `File-B` contains the dummy text

```
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 N
```

in line 6. This dummy text is also identical in every `Folder`. I need to replace this dummy line with the correct line in every `Folder`, so that every `File` within one `Folder` contains the same string on line 6.

My guess is that `sed` is the right tool for that but I don't know how to set it up to use different strings as input. The basis would be

```
sed -i 's/String1/String2/g' file
```

The rough sketch that I envision is:

```
for i in */;
     do for j in 2 3;
     do sed  6th line in "$i"Subfolder-1/File-A > 6th line in "$i"Subfolder-"$j"/File-B               % Magic needed
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed can print a particular line in a file:

```sh
sed -n '6p' file
# store it to a variable via
replacement=$(sed -n '6p' file)
```

Instead of a replace (which would not work well if your 6th line matched other lines in your file), you can delete the old 6th line and insert your new 6th line before line 7:

```sh
sed -i -e '6d' -e "7i$replacement" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this in stages.

We'll need the `find` command. To find all of the Folders:

```
find . -name "Folder-*"
```

So far, so good. Now to do something with each folder:

```
find . -name "Folder-*" | while read dname; do
  echo $dname
done
```

Now to extract the good line from File-A:

```
find . -name "Folder-*" | while read dname; do
  echo $dname
  good=`sed -n '6p' $dname/Subfolder-1/File-A`
  echo $good
done
```

Now to find all of the File-Bs, using an inner `find`, specific to the Folder:

```
find . -name "Folder-*" | while read dname; do
  echo $dname
  find $dname -name File-B
done
```

Now to modify each of those files by having the inner `find` execute a `sed` command, replacing each sixth line with "placeholder":

```
find . -name "Folder-*" | while read dname; do
  echo $dname
  find $dname -name File-B -exec sed -i '' "6s/.*/placeholder/" {} \;
done
```

Now to put it all together, and use the variable `good`:

```
find . -name "Folder-*" | while read dname; do
  good=`sed -n '6p' $dname/Subfolder-1/File-A`
  find $dname -name File-B -exec sed -i '' "6s/.*/$good/" {} \;
done
```